# .gitignore not ignoring .cs.meta files

Tags: git, github, gitignore

All I want is for for git to ignore files that end in `.cs.meta`.
My `.gitignore` file includes just this:

```
# ignore all .cs.meta files
*.cs.meta
```

How can ignore only files that end in `.cs.meta`?

Comment: That will work fine, but of course you'll have to remove any existing `.cs.meta` files from version control.

Comment: If you have already versioned these `.cs.meta` files, you'll first have to use `git rm --cached` to remove them from the repository, before the `.gitignore` will have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ignore ignore all .cs.meta files you just need to add

```
*.cs.meta
```

in your .gitignore file.

You did it! Maybe is not working because you added them to .gitignore after  their repository addition. You now need to remove them from the git repository:

```
git rm file.cs.meta
```

and then commit again.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure any of your ignored file is *not* present in the index:

```
git ls-files --ignored --exclude-standard -z|xargs -0 git rm --cached
git commit -am "Remove ignored files"
```

Then you can check if your files are ignored with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- /path/to/a/file.cs.meta
```

It should display your ignore rule now.